# Pointer changes after return from function

Tags: pointers, struct, tree, segmentation-fault, avl-tree

I was implementing a Tree for a company which I had to link to an AVL Tree for log n search.

The search function inside the AVL Tree is:

```
node* searchNode(string S, node* root) //(S,root)
{
    if (root->Name == S)
    {
        if (root->present == 1)
        {
            cout<<"root found"<<endl;
            cout<<root<<endl;
            return root;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"not found"<<endl;
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    else if (S > root->Name)
    {
        cout<<"search shifted right"<<endl;
        searchNode(S, root->right);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"search shifted left"<<endl;
        searchNode(S,root->left);
    }
}
```

And another function is:

```
node* search(string S)
{
    cout<<"started search"<<endl;
    node *searchResult;
    searchResult = companyTree.searchNode(S,companyTree.root);
    cout<<searchResult<<endl;
    cout<<"finished search"<<endl;
    return searchResult;
}
```

The problem is that the

```
cout<<root<<endl;
```

and the

```
cout<<searchResult<<endl;
```

do not give the same pointer address. Moreover, when I try to access any element of the node returned from the search(S) function, I get a segmentation fault. What should I do?

The struct node is:

```
struct node
{
    string Name; 
    node *left;
    node *right;
    employee* self;
    int present; //1 if present, 0 if absent
    node()
    {
        Name= " ";
        left= NULL;
        right=NULL;
        self=NULL;
        present=-1;
    }   
};
```

Comment: You're not handling the return value from your recursive calls to searchNode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add return where you are calling the function recursively.

```
node* searchNode(string S, node* root) //(S,root)
{
    if (root->Name == S)
    {
        if (root->present == 1)
        {
            cout<<"root found"<<endl;
            cout<<root<<endl;
            return root;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"not found"<<endl;
            return NULL;
        }
    } 
    else if (S > root->Name)
    {
        cout<<"search shifted right"<<endl;
        return searchNode(S, root->right);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"search shifted left"<<endl;
        return searchNode(S,root->left);
    }
```

Hope this works.